# Component update

Tags: javascript, svelte-component, svelte-3

I am trying to trigger a component update on value change

It works on css update for example '$: cssColorValue = calcRandomColor()' but not if I am using an array for example '$: values = [...newValues]'

```
<script>
  import Chip from "./Chip.svelte";
  import st from "../style-config.js";
  export let width = st.chip_bar.width;
  export let height = st.chip_bar.height;
  let border = st.chip_bar.border;
  export let center = false;
  export let color = "";
  export let cl = "";
  export let close = true;
  export let values = [];
  export let disabled = "";
  let value = "";

  function add_value(event) {

    if (event.code === "Enter") {
      values.push(value);
      console.log(values);
      value=''
    }
  }

  function remove_value(e) {
    console.log(e);
    var index = values.indexOf(e.value);
    if (index > -1) {
      arr.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  $: input_style = ` text-black w-auto h-auto font-medium ml-1 outline-none ${cl}`;

  $: chip_bar_style = ` ${
    st.round
  } text-black w-${width} h-${height} text-middle ${
    border ? "border" : ""
  } outline-none ${st.shadow} ${
    st.chip_bar.border
  } pl-1 pr-1 pt-1 pb-1 inline-block ${cl}`;
</script>

<div class="{chip_bar_style} on:hover={st.chip_bar.focus}">
  {#each values as text}
    <Chip {text} on:click={remove_value} />
  {/each}
  <input
    type="text"
    class={input_style}
    bind:value
    on:keydown={add_value}
    {disabled} />
</div>
```

What I would like is for Svelte to rerender the for each loop

Comment: using array methods like push and splice won't automatically cause updates. See https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects

Comment: I missed that one thanks @collardeau but still it doesn't seem efficient copying the array every time

Answer (score 0):

Copied from the official documentation

Because Svelte's reactivity is triggered by assignments, using array methods like push and splice won't automatically cause updates. For example, clicking the button doesn't do anything.

One way to fix that is to add an assignment that would otherwise be redundant:

```js
    function addNumber() {
        numbers.push(numbers.length + 1);
        numbers = numbers;
    }
```

But there's a more idiomatic solution:

```js
    function addNumber() {
        numbers = [...numbers, numbers.length + 1];
    }
```

You can use similar patterns to replace pop, shift, unshift and splice.

Assignments to properties of arrays and objects — e.g. obj.foo += 1 or array[i] = x — work the same way as assignments to the values themselves.

```js
    function addNumber() {
        numbers[numbers.length] = numbers.length + 1;
    }
```